# excel average a column for the last 90 days

Tags: excel

I'm using `excel 2010` on `windows 7 professional`.

I have a table where :

- column 1 is DATE(excluded weekend),
- column 2 is numbers.

I would update this table everyday to get new data for the day.

I would like to make a function that **calculate the average column 2 for the last 90 days**. (column 2 numbers comes from a Vlookup data table)

Initially I tried this formula, and I got an error :

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="today()-90,A:A,"<="today())
```

[i copied the data to a google sheet so i can share](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BlrYxVZoBVKAMDlVUJ4iX0oJMyMMVqYKbDPsp-lVGxM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&F6,A:A,"<="&F7)
```